# How to "spread" a single row in SQL server into multiple rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called 'counts' which returns rows in the following form:

```
SELECT Name,
       PassCount,
       WarningCount,
       FailCount
FROM counts

╔════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Name  PassCount   WarningCount   FailCount ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Jeff  12          2              0         ║
║ Dan   0           0              1         ║
║ Mike  0           0              0         ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

What I want to achieve is to "spread" the results of the query out such that any rows that contain non-zero values in more than one of the PassCount, WarningCount, FailCount fields have a separate row for each non-zero value appearing in said count and zeros filled out elsewhere. I am looking to achieve a result like below, but I am very inexperienced with SQL Server and don't really know how to achieve this.

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Name  PassCount   WarningCount   FailCount ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Jeff  12          0              0         ║
║ Jeff  0           2              0         ║
║ Dan   0           0              1         ║
║ Mike  0           0              0         ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

As you can see the row containing the Name Jeff has been "spread" into two rows since it had a non-zero PassCount and WarningCount. Hopefully this makes some sense. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the query that you want looks like this:

```
SELECT Name, PassCount, 0 as WarningCount, 0 as FailCount
FROM counts
WHERE PassCount > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, 0 as PassCount, WarningCount, 0 as FailCount
FROM counts
WHERE WarningCount > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, 0 as PassCount, 0 as WarningCount, FailCount
FROM counts
WHERE FailCount > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT NAME, 0, 0, 0
WHERE PassCount = 0 AND WarningCount = 0 AND FailCount = 0;
```

If I were looking to spread the results into multiple rows, I would do something like this:

```
SELECT c.name, v.col, v.val
FROM Counts c CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES ('PassCount', c.PassCount), ('WarningCount', c.WarningCount),
             ('FailCount', c.FailCount)
     ) v(col, val)
WHERE v.val > 0;
```

However, "Mike" would not appear in the results.

Answer (score 0):

just use UNION ALL and checks for  <> 0 for each column

```
SELECT Name,
       PassCount,
       WarningCount = 0,
       FailCount = 0
FROM counts
WHERE  PassCount <> 0
union all
SELECT Name,
       PassCount = 0,
       WarningCount,
       FailCount = 0
FROM counts
WHERE WarningCount <> 0
union all
SELECT Name,
       PassCount = 0,
       WarningCount = 0,
       FailCount
FROM counts
WHERE FailCount <> 0
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you. Is there anyway to make the solution a little more compact? My true situation has actually many more types of counts which leaves me with a 140 line long query.

Comment: @MichaelNicholson . . . How can this work perfectly?  It would not return "Mike".